# Specific input from user

Tags: java, applet, textfield

I started making my own little applet with buttons and labels and text fields, but I want to when you enter a certain thing in the text field it does something. I tried `if(fieldTextField.equals(mystringhere)) {` but it doesn't work. Could you post an example of what I want?

Comment: Post the entire code please.

Comment: someone might steal it no.

Comment: @NaameNameee do you work for NASA? no, so don't be afraid, noone is stealing your code.

Comment: fine. here: http://pastebin.com/ABJixz6Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a KeyListener, so that you can listen to keyboard and check your text everytime the user types something in your field:

```
KeyListener kl = new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt)){
        if(yourTextField.getText().equals(yourString){
            //do something here
        }
    }
};
yourTextField.addKeyListener(kl);
```

Note that `yourTextField` must be an instance variable or a local **final** variable in order to be used in the KeyListener methods

Comment: make a local **final** variable?

Comment: @NaameNameee Well, if your variable is `field1TextField` it already is an instance variable, so you don't need to make it final. Also, i see that all your GUI components are from java.awt package. When you can, please use javax.swing package, it is much better, there are two links that explain you why swing is better than awt: [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt) [link 2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26970)

Comment: my field1TextField is a simple textfield. `TextField field1TextField = new TextField("Insert Text Here");`

Comment: and one more thing, javax.swing?  i dont know how to use that. ill post another question about that

Comment: Did you check the two links i gave you? they explain it

Comment: and you forgot to add an extra ) to your public void

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at event listeners (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html). Also you shouldn't be comparing the TextField itself to the String, but it's text, using the getText() method.

EDIT: Better than the link above: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html