# Swing button vs AWT button?

Tags: java, swing, button, netbeans, awt

I'm in the beginnings of making a Minesweeper game for a final class project, but before I begin on making the GUI that is required for it, I would like some advice on what buttons to use.

Should I be using an AWT or Swing button? And which would benefit the program more?

I'm using Netbeans if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Few people develop in AWT anymore. (Hover your mouse over the AWT and Swing buttons in your question. You will see 61 people follow AWT questions and 1.3k follow Swing).

I would use Swing. Spend your time learning a more current API and its features.

Start with the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Swing generally.  The main reason being is Swing was designed to replace/enhance AWT.

Swing is, generally, more configurable and flexible to use.

You should avoid mixing AWT and Swing components within the same UI, they tend not to play well together.

There is more support and information available for Swing components (not to mention a large community of 3rd party components and developers)

You could also take a look at [AWT vs Swing](http://dn.embarcadero.com/article/26970) and [What is the difference between Swing and AWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt) for more details