# How to display default system icon for files in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to display default system icon for files in `JFileChooser`? i.e. the icons of the  files in `JFileChooser` should be the same as the icons that appear on desktop and explorer?

For example, NetBeans icon will not appear the same in `JFileChooser` as it appears on the desktop!

How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the `FileSystemView` class and get it's object by calling `getFileSystemView()` static method in it and then use the `getSystemIcon()` method which takes a `File` object and returns it's icon.

`FileSystemView` and `FileView` classes are present in `javax.swing.filechooser` package.
`File` class is in the `java.io` package.

**Note:** `FileSystemView` does not extend `FileView`. Hence you cannot use `FileSystemView` object in `jf.setFileView()`

```
JFileChooser jf=new JFileChooser();
jf.setFileView(new MyFileView());
jf.showOpenDialog(this);

class MyFileView extends FileView
{
      public Icon getIcon(File f)
      {
      FileSystemView view=FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            return view.getSystemIcon(f);
      }
}
```

`this` represents the current frame. Assume that the class in which this code is written is sub class of `JFrame`

Or in a simple way,

```
jf.setFileView(new FileView(){
            public Icon getIcon(File f)
            {
                return FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(f);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

The way shown by @JavaTechnical is one way.  Here is another (easier) way.  Set the GUI (or at least the file chooser) to the native PLAF.  E.G.

[image: File chooser with native PLAF]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FileChooserIcons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 30, 20, 30));

                JButton browse = new JButton("Show File Chooser");
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("File Chooser");
                ActionListener showChooser = new ActionListener() {

                    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jfc.showOpenDialog(f);
                    }
                };
                browse.addActionListener(showChooser);
                gui.add(browse);

                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you are feeling brave, you might create a custom file chooser starting with something like the [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

[image]

Comment: Hmm. That is good! What if i want to change the look and feel, say I love NimbusLookAndFeel! ;)

Comment: @JavaTechnical  *"I love NimbusLookAndFeel"* You love bugs?  Nimbus is one of the most bug ridden PLAFs ever developed.  ..And that is saying something!

Comment: +1 OK. By the way how do you feel about the way it looks and the way it can be customized? :)

Comment: Umm.. I have no strong opinions or feelings on that.  I've never tried customizing a `JFileChooser` (beyond the obvious 'PLAF').

Comment: I warmly remember that program and its development! 1+