# How does AWT process input so i can validate it

Tags: java, awt, textfield

After reasearching a few hours i did not find any information on how awt does process the input to any kind of listener. The problem is that i have to extend from VTextField (It is used in Oracle Forms). This class does use awt only. Basicly i would like to have something similar to the Documentlistener for the JTextField. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt/408830#408830) article i am a bit scared that the os does process the input into the textfield. Is anyone able to confirm this or how it is possible to listen to any kind of input?

Thanks for reading this in advance.

Comment: hmmm most of Listeners is from AWT packages, only a few hight abstraction or Listeners (swing.Text, JList, JTable) added in Java5/6 are from imports from Swing packages

Comment: Basicly i would like to have something similar to the Documentlistener for the JTextField. == awt.TextListener

Comment: Thanks, the textlistener is working. I tried the inputMethodListener, which had the same method as the Textlistener and was wondering why it did not work...

Comment: test whats firing TextListener.textChanged(text, previousText);, I'd to store history in array???, Map???, phaaaaa, I'm really don't know, brrrr

Comment: I think the real answer may be only from/by Andrew Thompson, camickr, Hovercraft Full Of Eels, StanislavL,

Comment: Can you tell me, how i should validate the existing Text against the input that has been done?

Comment: I don't know how to store previousText as I alread commented ....

Answer (score 0):

AWT is not meant to be intercepted by Java code. However your idea of looking at input methods was the right direction. Here is an example class that will filter simple insertions of 'a' chars out of the events going to the text field. It might serve as a starting point.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.im.InputContext;
import java.lang.Character.Subset;
import java.util.Locale;

class SpecialTextField extends TextField {
    InputContext customIC=new InputContext() {
      @Override
      public void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) {
        if(event.getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
          KeyEvent ev=(KeyEvent)event;
          if(ev.getKeyChar()=='a') {
            ev.consume();
            return;
          }
        }
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().dispatchEvent(event);
      }
      public boolean selectInputMethod(Locale locale) {
        return SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(locale);
      }
      public Locale getLocale() {
        return SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().getLocale();
      }
      public void setCharacterSubsets(Subset[] subsets) {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().setCharacterSubsets(subsets);
      }
      public void setCompositionEnabled(boolean enable) {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().setCompositionEnabled(enable);
      }
      public boolean isCompositionEnabled() {
        return SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().isCompositionEnabled();
      }
      public void reconvert() {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().reconvert();
      }
      public void removeNotify(Component client) {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().removeNotify(client);
      }
      public void endComposition() {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().endComposition();
      }
      public void dispose() {
        SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().dispose();
      }
      public Object getInputMethodControlObject() {
        return SpecialTextField.super.getInputContext().getInputMethodControlObject();
      }
    };
    @Override
    public InputContext getInputContext() {
      return customIC;
    }
  }
```

The `dispatchEvent` method is the place where the magic happens. All other methods just delegate to the original InputContext to allow real input methods to continue to work.

Comment: DYM to wrote own shouldYieldFocus() and verify() with aka DocumentFilter based on KeyboardFocusManager/KeyListener