# Java Style About JFrame and DefaultCloseOperation

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Particularly new to Java, and I have a simple style/design/syntax question:
when creating a JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

is the JFrame before EXIT_ON_CLOSE necessary? Isn't it already specified with using frame.setDefault...?

One last question is are there any particular benefits to using JFrame instead of Frame?
Pros & Cons?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: everything is descibed in Oracle tutorials How to use Frames and WindowListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the JFrame before EXIT_ON_CLOSE necessary? Isn't it already
>   specified with using frame.setDefault...?

It's necessary cause [JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) is a constant (class level variable). 
that when you set, exit the application using the System exit method.

you can ommited it, if you make a static import like this.

Example with static import:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Test{

  public static void main(String args[]) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }        
}
```

> One last question is are there any particular benefits to using JFrame
>   instead of Frame? Pros & Cons?

JFrame is from swing, and Frame is more outdated from awt. Here you have more information [Swing vs AWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt)

Comment: It's necessary cause JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE it's a constant(class level variable ). you can ommited if you make a static import., not wrong JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE terminating current JVM

Comment: @mKorbel don't understand your english , sorry xD

Comment: Thanks for the help! but I don't understand the import statement nor the WindowsConstant, do you mean my NAME constant? bad practice? Could you go a little further in depth? Thank You!

Comment: @Otanan That comment was a side note to swing designers, not you.. is a bad practice using an interface wich holds only constants and no methods.. JFrame implements WindowConstants.. I delete that comment cause creates confussion

Comment: @nachokk thank you! turns out I was already extending JFrame which is why it didn't give me an error, and that explained the whole concept of the passing in a constant. This really helped me understand, I appreciate it so much!

Comment: @Otanan then the example you provided in your question is not correct cause there you are not extending , but im glad to hear that you understand and you solve yourself!

Answer (score 2):

EXIT_ON_CLOSE is a static variable belonging to the JFrame class. It's pretty standard to use it by specifying JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, but you could also import it if it really bothers you.

The Math class has similar static variables.

JFrame is Swing, Frame is AWT. That's a good place to start a google search.

Answer (score 2):

> is the JFrame before EXIT_ON_CLOSE necessary? Isn't it already
>   specified with using frame.setDefault...?

Yes, because you need to provide correct exit behavior you want when closing the Application frame: There are four such constant available:

- `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`: Don't do anything; Use it if you require the program to handle the closing operation and do some thing on window close event; you can use Window Listeners here
- `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` : Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered `WindowListener` objects. So register WindowListener to your `JFrame`  if required.
- `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` : Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered `WindowListener` objects.
- `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`: Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

All this constants are defined in `WindowCOnstants` interface. However, as you wanted to know the default value set as the Default close operation: it is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`

**Reference:**

1. [setDefaultCloseOperation(int operation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

Comment: That's 90% truth, JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE hides or shadow (never remember wich one) windowsConstant.EXIT_ON_CLOSE so that constant is defined in  JFrame. i don't know why they don't remove it, JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE since java 1.3 and WindowConstant.EXIT_ON_CLOSE since java 1.4

Comment: @nachokk EXIT_ON_CLOSE to shutdown current JVM instance (note there is an issue with one of non_deamon threads, but not main issue in this question)

Comment: @mKorbel i said another thing xD don't know why we never understood each other is not the first time haha

Comment: im not clear i think, my question is : why exist in JFrame class a constant that "hides/shadows"(don't remember now which is one) WindowsConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE? I know that in JFrame already exist since 1.3 and in windowsConstant since 1.4 but why they don't remove at their time. You can still refer as `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` cause implements WindowsConstant

Comment: @nachokk, now i get you. Sorry misunderstood. Yes it seems that As `JFrame` is implementation `WindowConstants`, there is still a declaration of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` which is hiding(Shadowing is not actually correct term here though i am sure you know it) `WindowConstants` fields. And the answer is... :(I don't know and don't tell it anyone) Programming fault may be (they forgot to remove it) :)

Comment: @Sage the answer always is backward compatibility but i don't see at this point.. i know the difference between hiding and shadowing but never remember wich one is i always have to read :D, you know my english is not too good

Comment: @nachokk, uhh don't worry so much about it. I am from Bangladesh and my English is not that good too: This is not something to be mentioned as great, the fact is that: We are participating here sharing our knowledge and that is what really great. :)

Answer (score 1):

[JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html)  is a Constant used to control the window-closing operation.
Same as `System.exit(0);` The Code may like this:

```
   protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
        super.processWindowEvent(e);

        if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            switch(defaultCloseOperation) {
              ...
          case EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
                  // This needs to match the checkExit call in
                  // setDefaultCloseOperation
        System.exit(0);
        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> > is the JFrame before EXIT_ON_CLOSE necessary? Isn't it already specified with using frame.setDefault...?

Yes it is necessary, because the constant `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` Is in the `JFrame` class. The only time when you would not need it is when you use a static import or are extending `JFrame`.

> > One last question is are there any particular benefits to using JFrame instead of Frame? Pros & Cons?

`JFrame` is part of the Swing library, Frame is part of the `AWT` library. Generally, Swing is more efficient and advanced than Awt

Comment: You might still need to specify JFrame even when extending JFrame, but a static import is another time in which you would not need to specify the JFrame class.

Comment: Still have an issue. Mostly with this phrase "The only time".  Your first example of extending a the JFrame class is correct, you don't need to specify JFrame, but a static import is another example.