# Invisible JButton in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, null-layout-manager

Here's my `JPanel`. The first button is always visible, but the secound is visible only when you place a cursour on it. Where the problem can be?

P.S. Please use simple english, if u can, because I don't speak english well

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{


GamePanel(){
    setLayout(null);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    JButton buttonShip1 = new JButton();
    buttonShip1.setLocation(10, 45);
    buttonShip1.setSize(40, 40);
    buttonShip1.setVisible(true);
    add(buttonShip1);

    JButton buttonShip2 = new JButton();
    buttonShip2.setLocation(110, 145);
    buttonShip2.setSize(440, 440);
    buttonShip2.setVisible(true);
    add(buttonShip2);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the code. For starters, why are you adding components in the `paint(Graphics)` method? You should also avoid using `setSize`, `setLocation` and `setLayout(null)`.

Comment: What the size of button `buttonShip2.setSize(440, 440);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid problems and learn Java Swing correctly, go check out their tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/).

There are too many problems to discuss here, so I'll try to keep it simple.

1. You're using a `null` layout. `null` layouts are avoided for the most part because there is usually a layout that does exactly what you want. It takes some time to get it working, but there are some defaults [in this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that are fairly simple to use. There are some nice pictures there that show you what you can do with each layout, too. If you use a layout manager, you generally don't need to use `setLocation, setSize` or `setVisible` on most components like JButtons.
2. You're calling the `paint` method in a Swing application. You want to call `paintComponent` because you're using Swing and not Awt. You also need to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method on the first line of the `paintComponent` method in order to correctly override the other `paintComponent` method.
3. The `paint`/`paintComponent` related methods are called very often. You don't want to create/initialize objects in them. The `paint`/`paintComponent` methods aren't a one time method like they may sound. They're continuously called and you should design your GUI around this. Design your `paint`-related methods to be **event-driven** rather than **sequential**. In other words, *program the `paintComponent` method with the mindset that your GUI is reacting to things continuously rather than running in sequential order like a normal program.* That's a very basic approach to it and hopefully doesn't confuse you, but if you go check out that tutorial you'll see what I mean eventually.

There are two basic types of GUIs in Java. One is `Swing` and the
    other is `Awt`. Check out [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt) for a
    nice description of the two.

Here is an example of what two buttons on a JPanel look like.

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();

        jframe.setContentPane(gp);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setSize(500,500);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }


    public static class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    GamePanel() {
        JButton buttonShip1 = new JButton("Button number 1");
        JButton buttonShip2 = new JButton("Button number 2");
        add(buttonShip1);
        add(buttonShip2);

        //setLayout(null);
        //if you don't use a layout manager and don't set it to null
        //it will automatically set it to a FlowLayout.
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // ... add stuff here later
            // when you've read more about Swing and
            // painting in Swing applications

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn's say about that, but those buttons have to move free if some keys are pressed, so can I use null layout?

Comment: I just gave you an example of some working code for a GUI to get you started. You can add the functionality on your own but I highly suggest you go through the tutorials I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for such a full answer, your answwer was helpful

Comment: If you want to move the components around, you should re-add them with their locations altered, but remember to do it in the context of the layout you choose. Once you get a grasp on how Swing works in Java, you can start using more advanced techniques like in camickr's (who is actually the other commenter!) ComponentMover tutorial: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't use a null layout
2. Don't create components in a painting method. The paint() method is for custom painting only. There is no need for you to override the paint() method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial [How to Use FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for a simple example that uses buttons and a layout manager.