# Java alternatives to AWT to capture mouse events?

Tags: java, awt

Are there alternatives to AWT for getting mouse press events in Java?

Comment: Is it just curiosity or you are having issues with AWT events?

Comment: eclipse rcp, swings, etc.

Comment: Yes it appears on Windows 7 AWT mousePressed events are delayed by 5 seconds (or until you release) when using a touch screen device. I need to be able to hold buttons down and have yet to find a way to do this.

Comment: Have you considered JavaFX? It is a better option for touch screen devices, or do you absolutely have to use AWT?

Comment: Absolutely have to use Swing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found lots of unanswered threads on this I'll share the solution. Turns out Windows 7 defaults Java to wm_gesture rather than wm_touch events so AWT does not get press events as expected. What you need to do is use JNA to register the window as a touch window (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Mouse event implies there's a window / frame on which the event occurred. Typically each GUI toolkit comes with its own list of event listeners / dispatchers. So the question should really be: **"What are the alternatives to AWT?"**

1. There's **Swing**. You can read about the difference between AWT and Swing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt) . (The answer also mentions **SWT**:

> Finally, you might also want to check out SWT (the GUI toolkit used
>   for Eclipse, and an alternative to both AWT and Swing), which is
>   somewhat of a return to the AWT idea of accessing native Widgets
>   through Java.

2. There's **JavaFX**, which is a more rich graphics framework and somewhat a successor of Swing. You can read about it on official Oracle JavaFX page [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) .

If we are talking about specific frameworks then (as far as I know they still use AWT event system underneath):

3. **JMonkey** game engine. [Official Page](http://jmonkeyengine.org/)
4. **LWJGL**. Light weight java gaming library. [Official Page](http://www.lwjgl.org/)

There are probably other frameworks but it seems the core functionality comes from AWT to handle native mouse query.

Comment: another noteworthy alternative is qtjambi, which is QT for Java

Comment: I have a Swing GUI but AWT mousePressed events are failing me so looking to see if there is another toolkit I could use to get those events for the swing GUI rather than AWT.