# background bleed-through when using getInsets

Tags: java, jframe

I'm currently struggling with the fact, that my the background of my frame is bleeding-trough. As result of that, the "background image" of my frame is always what was behind the frame at the moment it got opened.

**How the problem looks like**

[image: How the frame does look]

**Code**

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class launcher extends JFrame{

    Button btn;

    public launcher() {
        this.setSize(400, 300);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                launcher l = new launcher();
                l.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {     
        String s = "Dieser String steht in der Mitte des Fensters";
        int breite = getSize().width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right;
        int hoehe = getSize().height - getInsets().bottom - getInsets().top;
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 15);
        FontMetrics fmetrics = getFontMetrics(font);
        int zeilenMitte = fmetrics.getAscent() - (fmetrics.getAscent() + fmetrics.getDescent()) / 2;

        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(s, getInsets().left + (breite - fmetrics.stringWidth(s)) / 2,
                getInsets().top + hoehe / 2 + zeilenMitte);

        g.drawRect(this.getInsets().left + 20, 
                this.getInsets().top + 20, 
                (int)this.getSize().getWidth() - this.getInsets().left - this.getInsets().right - 40,
                (int)this.getSize().getHeight() - this.getInsets().top -  this.getInsets().bottom -40);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(45, 55, 200, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString("gefülltes Rechteck", 50, 80);

    }

}
```

**What I have already tried**

I deleted some parts of my code, to see where the problem itself is located. After the tests, I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere here **(Line 42)**:

```
g.drawString(s, getInsets().left + (breite - fmetrics.stringWidth(s)) / 2,
            getInsets().top + hoehe / 2 + zeilenMitte);
```

After I removed the line, it looks like this (how it should look).

[image: How the frame should look]

But of course it isn't my goal, to just remove the line and forget about it...

**Note**

Please don't complain about the structure of my code. I'm currently learning this new language with following book:

> Java 2 SDK v 1.4.0 book of Vorcon

So I'm just trowing some commands together and will mind the structure later.

Comment: javax.swing != java.awt. Use one of them. Do not mix.

Comment: @Wufo Can't really see what is wrong about it. I'm just importing automatically what Eclipse is suggesting me. I would be grateful for an explanation

Comment: try `public class launcher extends Frame{..`

Comment: @Wufo It solved my problem, thanks. In this case I think i mixed JFrame and Frame up... I will look it up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408820/what-is-the-difference-between-swing-and-awt
No problem. You're welcome.