# Using inspect.exe or UISpy.exe on java swing on Windows 10

Tags: swing, automation, windows-10

Am I correct in assuming that tools like inspect.exe and UIspy.exe cannot handle java elements in a window?  Consider this login box which has java elements (Login, Password, OK, Cancel).  Login is not to be confused with the name of the window which is also login.

When I try to inspect the elements I can see only Login (window name), system menu bar and close (the X).  I can't see any of the Java fields.  Someone told me that he thought inspect.exe could not see Java fields and it could handle only the outer window.  I haven't been able to verify.  Is this true.  If so what other tools are there to automate windows with Java fields?  We will no longer be using Test Complete, so would need something else that runs on Windows 10.

Comment: Is there a question here? Please explain what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Swing, tools like inspect.exe cannot tell what's inside the window because Swing:

> paints pictures of buttons, labels, text, checkboxes, etc., into [a] window...[so they are] meaningless pixels within a window from your OS's point of view.

If you use AWT, tools like inspect.exe will work because AWT:

> uses the underlying OS or native GUI toolkit...[so] your OS knows about them

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/408830/